# is it possible to set the region Google Cloud Dataflow uses at a project or organisation level?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

My employers recently started using Google Cloud Platform for data storage/processing/analytics.
We're EU based so we want to restrict our Cloud Dataflow jobs to stay within that region.
I gather this can be done on a per job/per job template basis with --region and --zone, but wondered (given that all our work will use the same region) if there's a way of setting this in a more permanent way at a wider level (project or organisation)?
Thanks
Stephen

Update:

Having pursued this, it seems that Adla's answer is correct, though there is another workaround (which I will respond with). Further to this, there is now an open issue with google this now which can be found/followed at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/113150550

I can provide a bit more information on things that don't work, in case that helps others:

Google support suggested changing where dataprep-related folders were stored as per [How to change the region/zone where dataflow job of google dataprep is running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46608136/how-to-change-the-region-zone-where-dataflow-job-of-google-dataprep-is-running) - unfortunately this did not work for me, though some of those responding to that question suggest it has for them.

Someone at my workplace suggested restricting Dataflow's quotas for non-EU regions here: https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas to funnel it towards using the appropriate region, but when tested Dataprep continued to favour using US.

Comment: Hi @Stephen, if you haven't come across this, I hope that this is what you're looking for. https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/concepts/regional-endpoints. There is also a note after the first section of text, that could be important to read as well.

Answer (score 0):

[Cloud Dataflow](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/concepts/regional-endpoints) uses us-central1 as a default region for each job and if the desired regional endpoint differs from the default region, the region needs to be specified in every Cloud Dataflow command job launched for it to run there. The zone will be automatically assigned workers to the best zone within the region, but you can also specify it with --zone.

As of this moment it is not possible to force the region or zone used by Cloud Dataflow based on the project or organization settings.

I suggest you to request a new [Google Cloud Platform feature](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187168&template=1162867). Make sure to explain your use case and how this feature would be useful for you.

As a workaround, to restrict the jobs creation on Dataflow for a specific region and zone, you can write a script or application to only create jobs with the specific region and zone you need. If you also want to limit the creation of jobs to be done only with the script, you can remove your users’ job [creation permissions](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/concepts/access-control) and only give this permission to a service account which would be used by this script

Answer (score 0):

A solution Google support supplied to me, which basically entails using Dataprep as a Dataflow job builder rather than a tool in of itself

1. Create the flow you want in Dataprep, but if there's data you can't send out of region, create a version of it (sample or full) where the sensitive data is obfuscated or blanked out & use that. In my case, setting the fields containing a user id to a single fake value was enough.
2. Run the flow
3. After the job has been executed once, in the Dataprep webUI under “Jobs”, using the three dots on the far right of the desired job, click on “Export results”.
4. The resulting pop up window will have a path to the GCS bucket containing the template. Copy the full path.
5. Find the metadata file at the above path in GCS
6. Change the inputs listed in the files to use your 'real' data instead of the obfuscated version
7. In the Dataflow console page, in the menu to create a job using a custom template, indicated the path copied from 2 as the “Template GCS Path”.
8. From this menu, you can select a zone you would like to run your job in.

It's not straightforward but it can be done. I am using a process like this, setting up a call to the REST API to trigger the job in the absence of Dataflow having a scheduler of it's own.